# Debian UEFI Boot with DELL Latitude 7490 "No bootable devices found"

Tags: ubuntu, debian, uefi

I have tried to install Debian 9.5 on a DELL Latitude 7490 with UEFI, but when I try to boot the machine I get the infamous `"No bootable devices found"`.
EFI partition has been created, and I can see the entry in `efibootmgr -v`.
I have tried to install Ubuntu with (apparently) the same settings and it works... I am a bit lost here.

Does anybody have any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to disable 'secure boot' option in the UEFI options, had the same problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, but it is already disabled

Comment: when you boot and go the configuration, are you able to see the hard disk? Also, is the GRUB boot loader installed? Just confirming the possible causes to your error.

Comment: And, please ass your findings to the original post; click on `edit` below it and to the left, and you will be able to add new information to your original post.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is not solved by disabling the secure boot feature then you should have a look at the following link:

https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#Quirks.2C_workarounds_and_special_UEFI_features_in_Debian_and_Debian-Installer

You may want to have a look at the section on the removable media path.

The section regarding the removable media path may be your problem, but I have no specifi knowledge if you Dell system has that problem.

If you think this may be the problem you can solve it manually to fix your installation using a bootable Debian usb stick and manually modify you EFI system Partition (ESP) as follows.  Debian default UEFI boot code on ESP is /EFI/debian/grubx64.efi mounted on /boot/efi.  Mount the ESP and create a new (as root) directory /EFI/boot and you copy /EFI/debian/grubx64.efi to /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi.

After this you should be able to boot.  Keep in mind that you probably still have to do the grub install fix mentioned in the wiki to make sure the bootx64.efi is updated with the rest of the system.

Comment: In the end I've installed Debian testing and it worked, so I don't really know what the problem was. Thanks for the tips though, I'll keep that in mind if I decide to give one more try to stable.

Comment: This was the right answer for me. Also note that in Dell BIOS you can add the .efi as a Boot Option under General > Boot Sequence. On Debian 12 it was /EFI/Debian/shimx64.efi that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for my Acer laptop. I had installed Debian in UEFI Mode, but booting produced a “No bootable device” error.

To fix this:

1. In BIOS, set supervisor password to access secure boot options, skip if you already can change secure boot options.
2. In your BIOS find the secure boot options section and navigate to "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing", then `hdd(number)`, Debian, select `grubx64.efi`, name it `grubx64` and say `yes`.

   Do this again but for `shimx64.efi`.
3. Save changes and reboot into BIOS and set this boot order:

   ```
   EFI File Boot 1: shimx64
   EFI File Boot 0: grubx64
   HDD(number): Debian drive
   ```
4. Save changes and reboot

This worked for me, I hope this helps.